# Прозрачный текст при наведении на кнопку

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть такая кнопка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.header {
    background-image: url(https://wallbox.ru/resize/640x480/wallpapers/main2/201717/art-ogni-kosmos-zvezdy-uzory-tumannost-rossyp-mercanie.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
}
.header__btn {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}

.header__btn:hover {
    color: transparent;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
<button class="header__btn">купить</button>
</header>
```

Как сделать чтобы текст при наведении стал прозрачным?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы текст вёл себя как дырка в кнопке? Типа кнопка стала белой, а через текст был виден космос под кнопкой?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Да, всё верно!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для реализации вашей задумки на CSS, нужно вмешаться и в HTML. А, именно - обернуть текст в `<span>`. Далее, при наведении, просто меняем *background-color* у `<button>` и цвет *text-shadow* у `<span>`:

```css
.header {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(https://wallbox.ru/resize/640x480/wallpapers/main2/201717/art-ogni-kosmos-zvezdy-uzory-tumannost-rossyp-mercanie.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
}

.header__btn {
  color: #f0f; /* Основной цвет */
  padding: 6px 28px;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: .15em;
  font: bold 96px 'Arial Black';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
.header__btn:hover { background-color: currentColor; }

.header__btn span {
  background-image: url(https://wallbox.ru/resize/640x480/wallpapers/main2/201717/art-ogni-kosmos-zvezdy-uzory-tumannost-rossyp-mercanie.jpg);
  background-position: -28px -6px; /* Смещение фона на величину отступов */
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 currentColor;
  transition: text-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
}
.header__btn:hover span { text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent; }
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <button class="header__btn"><span>купить</span></button>
</header>
```

Анимация именно *text-shadow* выбрана потому, что остальные свойства или не дружат с *transition* или негативно влияют на производительность. Текст увеличен для наглядности.

Answer (score 2):

В css есть [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask). Можно попробовать его. Но эта фича поддерживается не всеми браузерами. Или можно использовать svg:

```css
div {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: blue;
}
button {
    background-color: transparent;
}
svg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
.btnBg {
    fill: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button>
        <svg>
            <defs>
                <mask id="mask">
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
                    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="black">test</text>
                </mask>
            </defs>
            <rect class="btnBg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask)"></rect>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

Я состряпал это по [доке на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking). У них очень неплохая документация по веб-технологиям. Рекомендую.

При наведении вам надо просто инвертировать цвета маски. Текст станет непрозрачным (белым), а фон прозрачным (чёрным).